# Поиск объектов Yandex Map Android

Tags: java, android, yandex-maps-api

Делаю приложение для Android с картами Яндекса. Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо вывести на карту метки по определенному запросу (например, "аптеки").

Каким образов это можно сделать?

P.S. Впервые работаю с картами, поэтому многого не знаю

Comment: Главный совет - если можете не использовать yandexMapKit - не используйте его. (используйте googlemaps)
Если всё же вынуждены использовать - прямое геокодирование yandexMapKit не поддерживает, и, вряд ли будет, судя по тому, что код библиотеки обновлялся последний раз 4 года назад.
Но, данную задачу реализовать наверняка можно, с использованием  Api самих карт.
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/